# Passing Measures as parameters in a Named Set - MDX

Tags: parameters, ssas, mdx, olap-cube, performancepoint

I am using `SSAS 2012`.

Lets say I have a date dimension `[Date].[Calendar Month].[Month]`.

I have several measures like `[Sales]`, `[Purchases]`, `[Commission]` etc.

I want to create a **Named Set** that calculates non-empty months as a **Calculated Member** in **Cube**.

For example

```
NonEmpty(
            [Date].[Calendar Month].[Month], 
            [Measure].[Sales]
         )
```

calculates non-empty months for `[Sales]` measure.

```
Nonempty(
           [Date].[Calendar Month].[Month], 
           [Measure].[Purchases]
         )
```

calculates non-empty months for `[Purchases]` measure and so on.

I would like to reuse the Named Set and pass measures like `[Sales]` and `[Purchases]` as **`parameters`**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with your MDX, but if it is going into Reporting Services, this might be helpful: http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2014/01/reporting-services-mdx-field-list-and-using-measures-on-rows/

Comment: Hey mmarie! Thanks for your input. I am required to create multitude of such kind of Named Sets with which I will create other Calculated Members and will later use in Performance Point Dashboard (SharePoint 2013)  to create KPIs and Score Cards.

Comment: Add a PerformancePoint tag to your question. There are some clever people subscribing to that tag that might be able to help.

Comment: I do not understand your requirement in detail, but maybe creating a dynamic set and omitting the measure altogether from the definition would work? You would then alter provide the measure to use as a context to this set.